# How to use ListView.FixedViewInfo?

Tags: android

i want to know how to use ListView.FixedViewInfo,

so i need some code spinet which shows a demo of how to use ListView.FixedInfo ,

can any one help me regarding on this.

Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not use `ListView.FixedViewInfo` directly. Use `addHeaderView()` or `addFooterView()` on `ListView`. Internally, that will use `ListView.FixedViewInfo`

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh: You cannot use `addFooterView()` this way, AFAIK. Take a look at my `EndlessAdapter` for another solution to your problem: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Comment: Thank You Mr.CommonsWare for ur Valuable Comments

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh: If you have additional questions, then start new **specific** StackOverflow questions about what problems you are encountering.